# Problems with Pushing Dataframe in MS SQL Database

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, database, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which I'm trying to push in a MS SQL database but it is giving me different errors on different approaches.

First I tried pushing using this command `df.to_sql('inactivestops', con=conn, schema='dbo', if_exists='replace', index=False)` which gives the following error:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

Secondly, I tried using this command

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO inactivestops (ogc_fid, lat, long, feature, rtiid, stop, route_number, routes_listed, rti, standard_vta_sign, two_sided_sign, other_agencies_signs, rti_decal, others_using_stop, adopt_a_stop, information_sign, other_info_sign, tactile_signs, pole, other_pole, vta_bench, ad_bench, metal_vta_benches, simmie_seat, private_benches, vta__trash_container, concrete_sidewalk, ac_asphalt_paving, no_improvements, bench_pad, shelter_pad, pcc_bus_pad, other_property, residential, government_property, sidewalk_width, boarding_area, pavement_condition, accessible_path_to_crossing, comments, photo_date, date_updated, amigo_id, date_visited, shelter, tc_with_shelter, tc_other, parking_restrictions, boarding_pavement, other_pad_type, adjacent_property, commercial_property, school, ada_accessible, curb_cuts, lighting_nearby, pcc_bus_pad_length, last_modified, trapeze_status, street_view, stopname, st_dir, st_loc, stopabbr, sp_documents, sp_gat, sp_g, sp_gwt, trapeze_id, onname, atname, city, jurisdiction, rs_sat_alight, rs_sat_board, rs_sun_alight, rs_wkdy_alight, rs_sun_board, rs_wkdy_board, stopname_proposed, consolidation, rs_wkdy_alight_old, rs_wkdy_board_old, rs_sat_board_old, rs_sat_alight_old, rs_sun_board_old, rs_sun_alight_old, wheelchair_boarding, rs_wkdy_board_2020, rs_sun_board_2020, rs_sat_alight_2020, rs_sat_board_2020, rs_wkdy_alight_2020, rs_sun_alright_2020) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                   row.ogc_fid, row.lat, row.long, row.feature, row.rtiid, row.stop, row.route_number, row.routes_listed, row.rti, row.standard_vta_sign, row.two_sided_sign, row.other_agencies_signs, row.rti_decal, row.others_using_stop, row.adopt_a_stop, row.information_sign, row.other_info_sign, row.tactile_signs, row.pole, row.other_pole, row.vta_bench, row.ad_bench, row.metal_vta_benches, row.simmie_seat, row.private_benches, row.vta__trash_container, row.concrete_sidewalk, row.ac_asphalt_paving, row.no_improvements, row.bench_pad, row.shelter_pad, row.pcc_bus_pad, row.other_property, row.residential, row.government_property, row.sidewalk_width, row.boarding_area, row.pavement_condition, row.accessible_path_to_crossing, row.comments, row.photo_date, row.date_updated, row.amigo_id, row.date_visited, row.shelter, row.tc_with_shelter, row.tc_other, row.parking_restrictions, row.boarding_pavement, row.other_pad_type, row.adjacent_property, row.commercial_property, row.school, row.ada_accessible, row.curb_cuts, row.lighting_nearby, row.pcc_bus_pad_length, row.last_modified, row.trapeze_status, row.street_view, row.stopname, row.st_dir, row.st_loc, row.stopabbr, row.sp_documents, row.sp_gat, row.sp_g, row.sp_gwt, row.trapeze_id, row.onname, row.atname, row.city, row.jurisdiction, row.rs_sat_alight, row.rs_sat_board, row.rs_sun_alight, row.rs_wkdy_alight, row.rs_sun_board, row.rs_wkdy_board, row.stopname_proposed, row.consolidation, row.rs_wkdy_alight_old, row.rs_wkdy_board_old, row.rs_sat_board_old, row.rs_sat_alight_old, row.rs_sun_board_old, row.rs_sun_alight_old, row.wheelchair_boarding, row.rs_wkdy_board_2020, row.rs_sun_board_2020, row.rs_sat_alight_2020, row.rs_sat_board_2020, row.rs_wkdy_alight_2020, row.rs_sun_alright_2020)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

which gives the following error:

```
pyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Operand type clash: int is incompatible with text (206) (SQLExecDirectW); [22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')
```

I have already tried changing the **DRIVER** to **SQL Server** & **SQL Server Native Client 11.0** but that doesn't solve the problem.

Following are my connection details:

```
    DRIVER_NAME = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
    SERVER_NAME = 'my_server'
    DATABASE_NAME = 'my_db'
    UID = 'my_user'
    PWD = 'my_pwd'

connection_string = f"DRIVER={{{DRIVER_NAME}}};SERVER={SERVER_NAME};DATABASE={DATABASE_NAME};Trust_Connection=yes;uid={UID};pwd={PWD}"
```

A sample of the data that I'm trying to push (All columns have the type "**TEXT**" in target table of MS SQL):

| ogc_fid | lat | long | feature | rtiid | stop | route_number | routes_listed | rti | standard_lok_sign | two_sided_sign | other_agencies_signs | rti_decal | others_using_stop | adopt_a_stop | information_sign | other_info_sign | tactile_signs | pole | other_pole | lok_bench | ad_bench | metal_lok_benches | simmie_seat | private_benches | lok__trash_container | concrete_sidewalk | ac_asphalt_paving | no_improvements | bench_pad | shelter_pad | pcc_bus_pad | other_property | residential | government_property | sidewalk_width | boarding_area | pavement_condition | accessible_path_to_crossing | comments | photo_date | date_updated | amigo_id | date_visited | shelter | tc_with_shelter | tc_other | parking_restrictions | boarding_pavement | other_pad_type | adjacent_property | commercial_property | school | ada_accessible | curb_cuts | lighting_nearby | pcc_bus_pad_length | last_modified | trapeze_status | street_view | stopname | st_dir | st_loc | stopabbr | sp_documents | sp_gat | sp_g | sp_gwt | trapeze_id | onname | atname | city | jurisdiction | rs_sat_alight | rs_sat_board | rs_sun_alight | rs_wkdy_alight | rs_sun_board | rs_wkdy_board | stopname_proposed | consolidation | rs_wkdy_alight_old | rs_wkdy_board_old | rs_sat_board_old | rs_sat_alight_old | rs_sun_board_old | rs_sun_alight_old | wheelchair_boarding | rs_wkdy_board_2020 | rs_sun_board_2020 | rs_sat_alight_2020 | rs_sat_board_2020 | rs_wkdy_alight_2020 | rs_sun_alright_2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3196 | 65.54611357 | -652.5415354 | Bus Stop | 102562 | 9999451 |  | 435 |  | Yes |  | None | No |  | No | None |  | None | Standard |  | 0 | 0 |  |  | 0 | 0 | Pad Only | Back of Curb | Not Applicable | No | Yes | None |  | Not Applicable | Not Applicable | 5 | Yes | OK | Yes | moving as department gives signal |  | 8/25/2000 0:00 | 16dc73c45f1e4d4ae2eb0b12d6a149c1 | 2016/05/16 17:28:14+00 | NO |  |  | None | Gravel |  | Sound Wall |  |  | Yes | Yes | None |  | 2017/07/20 20:12:01.447+00 | Inactive | https://example.com/base/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=54512.641616,-85413216.361125&cbp=11,0,0,0,0&ll=54512.641616,-85413216.361125&z=10 | example stop 1 | N | FS | JSDFBSFSF |  | https://aunt.example.org/bag/attraction.htm?bee=apparel&birds=bee.jpg |  | https://aunt.example.org/bag/attraction.htm?bee=apparel&birds=bee.JPG | 4607 | SJKDSNDF | SDFSFS | GFDS | DF |  |  |  | 3 |  | 4 |  |  | 7 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 770 | 65.54123565 | -652.510654 | Bus Stop | 623448 | 6665128 |  | wemo laya | No | No |  | None | Yes |  | No | Transit Type |  | None | Street Light |  | 0 | 0 |  |  | 0 | 0 | Monolithic | Not Applicable | Not Applicable | No | No | No |  | Not Applicable | Other | 8 | Yes | OK | Yes |  |  | 6/30/2000 0:00 | e38c554c04bd29b7f5ca5f8fe1971418 | 2018/04/04 19:08:00+00 | NO |  |  | No Stopping Sign |  |  |  | Parking Lot |  | Yes | Yes | S.L. Same Side |  | 2018/04/04 19:06:32+00 |  | https://example.com/base/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=54512.641616,-85413216.361125&cbp=11,0,0,0,0&ll=54512.641616,-85413216.361125&z=10 | example stop 2 | N | MD | FDSDFPO |  | https://aunt.example.org/bag/attraction.htm?bee=apparel&birds=bee.jpg |  | https://aunt.example.org/bag/attraction.htm?bee=apparel&birds=bee.JPG | 2 | DSFSDFFDSA | DFSFS | HGF | FG | 79 | 101 | 94 |  | 120 |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 65.54698657 | -652.5964354 |  | 639410 | 3332154 | 32, 41 | former proposed action |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 10' |  |  |  | need 17" improvement |  |  | 51f0ee7975e2d49fa97bf626714684f6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2019/12/04 18:41:36.602+00 | Inactive | https://example.com/base/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=54512.641616,-85413216.361125&cbp=11,0,0,0,0&ll=54512.641616,-85413216.361125&z=10 | example stop 3 | N | FS |  |  |  |  |  | 5924 | DFSDSFS | SFSDFSDF | FD | DSF |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 65.56301357 | -652.5309354 | Bus Stop | 312589 | 5552566 | 60 | 283 SB |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | n/a |  |  |  | 10/24/19 making it bigger for NHAA |  |  | 9861e5657779d4c06e41331a29aa06ae |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2019/10/25 00:57:33.993+00 | Inactive | https://example.com/base/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=54512.641616,-85413216.361125&cbp=11,0,0,0,0&ll=54512.641616,-85413216.361125&z=10 | example stop 4 | N | AT |  |  |  |  |  | 5950 | SFSFSF | SFSFSF 4536 | DF |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Aside... `Trust_Connection=yes;` seems like a typo. It would normally be `Trusted_Connection=yes;` which enables Windows/Active Directory/Kerberos authentication using the identity token of the currently running process, and so you either use that or you use `uid={UID};pwd={PWD}` but you don't use both together.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server, or an SQLite database file? The presence of `sqlite_master` suggests you're trying to use an SQLite database file by way of the ODBC driver for Microsoft SQL Server - but those are incompatible database systems.